# sum group values based on factor from second data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames - one containing a list of all samples (sample ID, area etc)(sampleid.df) and a second a list of counts (obs.count) made in each sample. What I need is a table which lists ALL samples and provides a sum for all obs.measur (by sampleid) - in addition samples returning no counts should get a 0. I tried aggregate and merge but the difference in length was an issue. Any ideas/suggestions much appreciated.

```
sampleid.df <- data.frame(sampleid = 1:20)
sampleid.df$sampleid <- as.factor(sampleid.df$sampleid)

obs.count  <- data.frame(counts = c(sample(1:50,15,rep=TRUE)), sampleid = c(sample(1:20,15,rep=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `merge` with option `all=TRUE` so that the output ("df1") will have NA for "sampleids" from "sampleid.df" that does not have a match in the same column from "obs.count".  Then use `aggregate` with option `na.action=na.pass` (by default, the option is `na.action=na.omit`) to include the NA rows as well.  Using `na.rm=TRUE` within `sum` remove the `NAs` but if a particular "sampleid" have only NAs, it will return NA.

```
df1 <- merge(sampleid.df, obs.count, all=TRUE)
res <- aggregate(counts~sampleid, df1, sum, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=na.pass)
res$counts[is.na(res$counts)] <- 0
```